# Creating a two-dimension linked list object in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have the following template and class

```
template<class T>
class LinkedList
{
....
....
}

class Editor
{
private:
LinkedList <LinkedList<char>> doc;   //My Question is how can I implement this? 
int line;
int col;

public:
Editor();
.......
//other functions
......
}
```

doc is like a two-dimension linked list keeping the nodes (characters which are inserted) according to lines and columns of the document.

My question is that how can I implement and use the "doc" instance in the constructor and other functions in the Editor class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is rather poorly presented, I might say. What is it you need to *do* with the list? What problem are you solving? Where are you stuck? Most important of all, why don't you use `std::list`?

Comment: I cant change the definition of the classes and templates [STL is forbidden].

Comment: Are you sure you really want to use linked lists for this? A `char` is only one byte, and even if using a singly-linked list on a 32-bit computer, you're adding 4 more bytes for the pointer "link". You probably would be safer with a vector of vectors or a 2-D array, both of which have significantly less overhead, and provide much better locality, as at least every row will be contiguous in memory.

EDIT: so is this homework? If so, you should tag it as such.

Comment: for example if it is LinkedList<char>> doc; so I can get the length of the linked list with getlength function by writing doc.getlength() but the way that the instance is created above[in my question] confused me cause it is a two-dimensional one. How can I call the functions for it? (like getlength function)

Comment: Lists don't support random access.  You'll have to get an iterator to the list element you want in the first dimension dereference it (to get the second dimension list, and call whatever member function on that second dimension list you want.  To get the iterator you'll have to cycle through with a loop or use one of the std::find/std::find_if, etc algorithms.

Comment: a linked list of linked lists sounds... horrid!

Comment: This is a piss poor solution to any sort of real world problem.  Come on professor, try harder.

Answer (score 0):

If linked list is a template class (as it is) then you should be able to do this just fine assuming that you always ensure the first-dimension list exists at a location before trying to populate the second dimension list supposedly at that location.

There's a variety of questions on SO related to this (I've seen a few with vectors, look around).

**Note one thing though - you have a syntax error here.**

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<char> >
```

has to be written **instead** of the line you had, spacing out your two >> chevrons.  The compiler will take it as a right-shift operator if you don't leave that space in there which may be why you think your code doesn't work.

Please refer to matthias' comment on your question as well though, syntax errors aside I completely agree with him on all accounts :)

Comment: I was under the impression that the most popular compilers were doing away with that need, since the C++11 standard now allows for treating the '>>' token as two right-chevrons when there's an unmatched left-chevron.

Comment: Ah, maybe they are (I wasn't aware of that, but I think it's a great improvement and definitely makes sense) - but the environment I work on currently wouldn't compile this, and there's a good chance his wont depending on what it is.

Comment: You are right w00te about the syntax of LinkedList<LinkedList<char> > I wrote it wrong, sorry for that.

Comment: I tagged it as howework :) I cant use a 2-D array or vector instead